# How does the mounting surface flatness affect radio altimeter reading?

Tags: altimeter

It is recommended that the antennas be installed on flat surfaces. For some UAVs, the bottom of the fuselage is very narrow and sharply curved away from the antennas. How does it affect the measurement error?